# How can I change some number of code and save at one go?

Tags: matlab, save

These are my data :

```
>>K1=M(1:40:6360,1);
K2=M(1:40:6360,2);

%First column extraction

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(K1)
xlabel('frame')
ylabel('x')
grid on
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(K2)
xlabel('frame')
ylabel('y')
grid on

%First column plot

>> K1=M(2:40:6360,1);
K2=M(2:40:6360,2);

%Second column extraction

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(K1)
xlabel('frame')
ylabel('x')
grid on
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(K2)
xlabel('frame')
ylabel('y')
grid on

%Second column plot

3rd and 4th .....
```

First, I plot first column and save the figure for example named 'A'

Then, I change 1 to 2 in a first two row of code and plot it and save it as 'B'.

It's tiresome. How can I change 1to2, 2to3,....,19to20 and save at a different name of file at one go?

Comment: Where's your `save the figure` command? Could you add that to your code for these two plots?

Comment: I save the figure firsthand at each time. There are no save code part of mine

Comment: Use a loop (combined with `saveas` ... you do not have to perform any manual step). Optionally, you can save your script to an m-file (script or function). In the case you have a variable that is named iteratively, use also `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

There might be better solutions, but I usually combine a `for` loop with `eval()` and `sprintf()`. This allows you to loop over the variables (K1,K2,...) rather than manually changing the names. Like this:

```
for i=1:20
    subplot(2,1,i)
    plot(eval(sprintf('K%i',i)))
    xlabel('frame')
    ylabel('x')
    grid on
end
```